# SPOJ Prime Generator, getting TLE, but approached with the best I could. (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, primes

The problem is to generate prime in between two interval, detail problem is given in this link.  [SPOJ Prime Generator](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/).
Let me explain the magic numbers and the algorithm I followed.
I have used modified  [Sieve Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm (modified in sense because I used the basic idea.) for implementation.

- Starting number of interval, **m** and End number of the interval **n** are <= 10^9 and the **difference** is <=10^5  (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000)
- There is no even prime number except 2, so I considered max **m and n** (10^9)/2
  and sqrt(max number) is around 32000 (considering both odd and even), finally 32000/2= 16,000 is the size of odd numbers list **input_aray**.
- Finally total number range is divided into 3 regiions.
- **m and n both >= 32000** in this case the size of the **input_aray** is **(n-m+1)/2** from 16001 index of array, numbers between m and n is stored (only odd numbers).
- **m and n <32000** in this case size of **input_aray** is upto n/2.
- **m <32000 and n>32000** in this case size of **input_aray** is **(n-32000+1)/2**.
- **Boolean** array **bol** of same size as **input_aray** is kept to track which number is visited so that two number can't be considered twice.

  `for (int j = 1; j < 16001; j++) {
        int flag = input_aray[j];`

This loop choose n index from **input_aray** and check if there is any number in this array that is divisible, if so then same index of **bol** is initialized into false.

`for (int k = j + flag; k <= 16000; k = k + flag)`

This loop check for prime numbers upto 32000.

`for (int k = 16001; k < input_aray.length; k++)`

This one checks in between ** m and n** (when m&n >=32000)

***This is the fastest approach I could implement, but still get Time Limit Exceed**. What could be the probable cause?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner take= new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    int m,n;
    int temp= take.nextInt();
    take.nextLine();
    if(temp>=0 && temp<=10){
        for(int i=0;i<temp;i++) {
            String temp1 = take.nextLine();
            arrayList.add(temp1);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
        String[] temp_aray= arrayList.get(i).split(" ");
        m= Integer.parseInt(temp_aray[0]);
        n= Integer.parseInt(temp_aray[1]);

        if(m>0 && n>0 && m<=10E8 && n<=10E8 && n-m<= 10E4 ) {
            if (m >= 32000 && n >= 32000) {
                //m & n > 32000
                int start;
                int[] input_aray = new int[16001 + ((n - m + 1) / 2) + 1];
                boolean[] bol = new boolean[16001 + ((n - m + 1) / 2) + 1];
                Arrays.fill(bol, true);
                input_aray[0] = 2;
                input_aray[1] = 3;

                for (int j = 2; j < 16001; j++) {
                    input_aray[j] = input_aray[j - 1] + 2;
                }
                if (m % 2 == 0) {
                    start = m + 1;
                } else {
                    start = m;
                }
                for (int j = 16001; j < input_aray.length; j++) {
                    input_aray[j] = start;
                    start += 2;
                }

                for (int j = 1; j < 16001; j++) {
                    int flag = input_aray[j];
                    for (int k = j + flag; k <= 16000; k = k + flag) {
                        if (input_aray[k] % flag == 0 && bol[k] == true) {
                            bol[k] = false;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int k = 16001; k < input_aray.length; k++) {
                        if (input_aray[k] % flag == 0) {
                            bol[k] = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                int num = 1;
                for (int j = 16001; j < bol.length; j++) {
                    if (bol[j] == true) {
                        System.out.println(input_aray[j]);
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();

            }

            if(m<32000 && n< 32000){
                int[] input_aray = new int[(n/2)+1];
                boolean[] bol = new boolean[(n/2)+1];
                Arrays.fill(bol, true);
                input_aray[0] = 2;
                input_aray[1] = 3;

                for (int j = 2; j < input_aray.length; j++) {
                    input_aray[j] = input_aray[j - 1] + 2;
                }

                for (int j = 1; j < Math.sqrt(n); j++) {
                    int flag = input_aray[j];
                    for (int k = j + flag; k<input_aray.length; k = k + flag) {
                        if (input_aray[k] % flag == 0 && bol[k] == true) {
                            bol[k] = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                int num = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < bol.length; j++) {
                    if (bol[j] == true && input_aray[j] >=m && input_aray[j]<=n) {
                        System.out.println(input_aray[j]);
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            if(m<32000 && n>32000){
                int start;
                int[] input_aray = new int[16001 + ((n - 32000 + 1) / 2) + 1];
                boolean[] bol = new boolean[16001 + ((n - 32000 + 1) / 2) + 1];
                Arrays.fill(bol, true);
                input_aray[0] = 2;
                input_aray[1] = 3;
                for (int j = 2; j < 16001; j++) {
                    input_aray[j] = input_aray[j - 1] + 2;
                }
                start=32001;
                for (int j = 16001; j < input_aray.length; j++) {
                    input_aray[j] = start;
                    start += 2;
                }
                for (int j = 1; j < 16001; j++) {
                    int flag = input_aray[j];
                    for (int k = j + flag; k <= 16000; k = k + flag) {
                        if (input_aray[k] % flag == 0 && bol[k] == true) {
                            bol[k] = false;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int k = 16001; k < input_aray.length; k++) {
                        if (input_aray[k] % flag == 0) {
                            bol[k] = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                int num = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < bol.length; j++) {
                    if (bol[j] == true && input_aray[j]>=m && input_aray[j]<=n) {
                        System.out.println(input_aray[j]);
                        num++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand your code or your description. Note that, given the size of the upper bound, a pure Sieve of Eratosthenes will be too slow and inefficient. A critical feature of this problem is that the size of the interval, n-m, is relatively small compared to the larger values of n and m. Also note that the smallest prime factor of any number < 10**9 must be <= 31621, and there are only a few thousand primes less than 31621.

Comment: I'm considering smallest prime factor upto 32000. Say the prime numbers are 2,3,5,7,11..... So, all prime numbers are odd except 2, there can be atmost 5 odd number in between 1 to 10.  So I'm cosidering 16000 odd numbers. input_aray[16000] = 31999